# JQuery - code behind

Tags: jquery

how would you use JQuery with asp.net Code-Behind

what i mean by that: i have a div that displays the result based on some processing and this process done on code-behind and based on that result i have to display if the process went through sucessfully or not.

how would i do and is that possible? can anybody show me some sample lines of code to understand?

thanks.

Comment: Why do you think you need jQuery in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it seems that your are confused over client vs server side processing.

if the process is running on your server, then you can add an asp:label to your div and then in the code-behind set your message to the label.

if the process is running on your client, then you can use jquery to set the message into your div.   uses $("#message").text("insert your message here")

Answer (score 1):

"[Using jQuery and OData to Insert a Database Record](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2010/03/30/using-jquery-and-odata-to-insert-a-database-record.aspx)" would be a link to an example of using jQuery with ASP.Net that would be a starting point for what you want I think.

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery library is a JavaScript Library that you can use to replace or work with your standard client-side JavaScript code. jQuery is used on the client to build rich interfaces and can be used to post/get data to and from the server, it wraps a lot of existing javascript, allows quicker development and is built to work across browsers.

Have a look at the [jQuery UI demos](http://jqueryui.com/demos/) to see what jQuery can do for your interface.
If you want to use it for ajax, its probably best to find a few tutorials or blogs to demonstrate working examples.

Answer (score 0):

Your code behind would render the result div if successful using an asp:panel control. You could give it a class eg CssClass='resultdiv'. If you make the panel visible = false, it wont get rendered to the client.

You can use the following jquery to get the panel element:

```
$('div.resultdiv').each(function() {

    //Client side code here

));
```